# How to change Google consent screen email?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I created new Google Play game and would like to change the email displayed on Google Consent Screen. Google Developers Console [screen](https://console.developers.google.com/project/760943112345/apiui/consent) has a dropdown to choose email, but just one - admin's email - is here. I've added another user as the owner, but it is not appeared on the consent screen.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need a second email address then add that person / email as admin of the project. Then you will be able to add that email in the consent screen.

The Console has changed a lot since 2014, You need to add another user as the admin then you must login to console with that email and connect it. Then you will be able to change it.

[image]

A new user can be added via the [Iam](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) for your project.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but second email didn't appear. But after 'playing` with login and logout (including login after second user and accepting all terms and conditions, it is appeared.

Comment: I know I have been there, it took me 2 days to figure it out the first time.

Comment: I found that it only worked when I actually logged out of my account, logged onto the new account, and then changed it.  Until the second email actually logged onto to the console, the second email did not appear.  I also jumped up and down on foot 3 times.

Comment: Similar experience to @LA_. Except, I used Incognito to login to the new GMail account, as to not destroy my session. From the new account, I was able to change the developer e-mail.

Comment: And more specifically, to add your *support@company.com* you must login to console with that email and connect it. By other email you can't add that support email.

Answer (score 74):

If you want to change the email address that is displayed to the user you have to:

1. Add permission for the new email address to handle the project: `Menu > IAM & Admin > IAM`, then click on the `Add` button, enter the email address and select `Role > Project > Owner`
2. Accept the invitation from the new email address. Check your emails, click on the confirmation url and accept the terms and conditions.
3. Log in to the Google Developers Console using the NEW email address. Only the new email address can change the displayed email address. You don't have to log out or open an incognito window. You can simply add a new account by clicking on your account photo (upper-right corner) and then selecting the `Add account` option.

Tip: When you visit the page, you will be logged in with your primary account by default. If you want to be logged in with the second account you just created, simply append `&authuser=1` to the end of the url. If you have more than 2 accounts, you can use the value authuser=2 or 3 and so on. (The default value for your primary account is 0.)

Comment: FU Google, this is insane! I should be able to fill in any email address at the console consent config screen, which by itself is already a freaking nightmare to find.

Comment: Note: they only allow you to add email addresses that are associated with Google accounts. This means you have to subscribe to their paid services to accomplish this. Also, in order to get an app verified, your support email must "accurately represents the app's identity." If they want us to pay to use their Auth, why not just charge us up front, instead of surprising us with this later?

Comment: I don't think you need a gmail account. You can use https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail to create a google account for a non-google email address. You must then go through the IAM process above. Note that I did have to refresh the IAM invite page after registering the new account in order for it to be recognized.

Comment: I have tried the steps above and google couldn't log me out and in with the email address which received the owner status report. After I manually logged out and in with the email address which received the owner status report I was able to select my "new" email in the popup. The project has 4 owners and only the logged in one is able to select himself as the support. This is really a bad UX/UI from google.

Comment: I have a Google account that doesn't have Gmail linked to it and managed to set it to that address using those steps.

Comment: This is not working at all

Comment: FYI, I managed to get this working by following what @Peter Trenery said, and after logging out and logging in again.

Answer (score 11):

You can go here https://groups.google.com/ and create a group. Then simply refresh the consent page and you'll be able to pick the group. It is not your custom domain but it does the job I think.

Answer (score 10):

While the above solutions work, I didn't want to make my support@my-company.com a `Project > Owner` of my GCP project since multiple people can potentially access it.

The page (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit) says that the permission needed is `clientauthconfig.clients.update`

So I made a Custom Role containing every permission in that category:

```
clientauthconfig.brands.create
clientauthconfig.brands.delete
clientauthconfig.brands.get
clientauthconfig.brands.list
clientauthconfig.brands.update
clientauthconfig.clients.create
clientauthconfig.clients.createSecret
clientauthconfig.clients.delete
clientauthconfig.clients.get
clientauthconfig.clients.getWithSecret
clientauthconfig.clients.list
clientauthconfig.clients.listWithSecrets
clientauthconfig.clients.undelete
clientauthconfig.clients.update
```

and gave my support email that Custom Role + the role `Project > Viewer`

One note, these permissions are not finalized yet. The 'Create a Custom Role' page gives this warning:

> Not recommended for production use
>
> These permissions might be changed
>   in backward-incompatible ways and are not recommended for production
>   use. They are not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.

Comment: To avoid creating a Custom Role, I just tried the `Firebase Develop Admin` role which has `clientauthconfig` permissions and it allowed me to change the `Support email`. At the top shows a warning "You don't have permission to edit the consent screen..", but I was able to save and the email was changed.

Comment: As reference, the list of Roles and Permissions is here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

Comment: I tried the `Firebase Develop Admin` but was still missing two permissions: `oauthconfig.testusers.get`
`oauthconfig.verification.get`
Adding `OAuth Config Editor` role in addition to Firebase role allowed the account to set the support email.

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to choose email without creating a new Gmail account and giving it Owner permissions. You can create a Group in GSuite with public email and then configure the group's forwarding to the email you want.

For example, you want to use `support@company.com`. You can create a group `support.google@company.com` which will forward everything to `support@company.com`

Then, you will be able to pick up `support.google@company.com` in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Krasimir's answer, you can also reuse an existing group as long as you're an "Owner" of that Google Group. In my case, I asked my IT Administrator to make me an owner of the group temporarily. I could then update the support email address in the console. After updating, the elevated permissions on the Google Group can be removed.