# Error adding member to a google api project (developer console)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth

Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access) for adding a new member to a project—pretty simple.
However, when I add a new member to the project, I get an error:

> Error
>
> The specified invitation was not found.

The member I'm adding is an alias account. When I say *alias account* I mean my main account (username@gmail.com) owns the project, and I'm trying to add a different email that I own (me@mydomain.com). me@mydomain.com is a sub account of username@gmail.com.

When I click the confirmation link, first I have to type in me@mydomain.com's password, then I am redirected to type in username@gmail.com's password, and finally I am redirected to the project where I get the ugly error staring me in the face.

I would be talking with google right now if I could, but I'm a *bronze* member…

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23107132/1433127) explains that if I want to change the email that displays on the oauth permissions screen, I need to add the email to the project. I'm trying to add the email to the project so I can display me@mydomain.com instead of username@gmail.com on the oauth permissions screen.

Comment: I've tried switching me@mydomain.com to a different gmail account, still no luck. It seems the problem is that after authenticating as me@mydomain.com, google redirects me to authenticate again at username@gmail.com, then redirects me back to the project as username@gmail.com instead of me@mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Looks like it [isn't possible](https://developers.google.com/multipleAccounts?continue=):</del>

> Because multiple sign-in is not supported, you will access Google Developers as your default account, username@gmail.com.

It is possible if you don't use sub-accounts! I got it working!

Instead of having me@mydomain.com as a sub-account of username@gmail.com, I had to remove me@mydomain.com from username@gmail.com, then create a new completely separate google account for me@mydomain.com. After doing that, everything was a cinch!